# What is the probability of selecting a red marble, then a blue marble if the first marble is replaced?

Tags: probability

A bag contains 4 green marbles, 9 red marbles, 10 orange marbles, 9 brown marbles, and 11 blue marbles. You choose a marble, replace it, and choose again. What is P (red, then blue)

This is my question that I have on my 8th grade pre-algebra homework and I was sick today at school so I was wondering how do I do this?

Comment: Please here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: While the best person you should ask is your teacher (they are supposed to be paid to teach you), given your sickness here's an outline of how to figure out the solution yourself: Think of probability as a measure of tendency to go down a particular path. In this question the first branching point is the choice of a marble from a given bag, and the two possible paths are (first marble red) and (first marble not red), so draw those. How likely would you go down each path? Now for each of the two resulting states, you have a second branching point and again two possible paths. [continued]

Comment: [continued] To be precise, you have a starting point $O$ which leads to two possible states $R$ (red) and $r$ (not red). From $R$ you can then reach either $RB$ (red,blue) or $Rb$ (red,not blue), and likewise from $r$ you can reach either $rB$ or $rb$. You should be able to easily determine how likely you would go from $R$ to $RB$ if you have already reached $R$. Do the same for each of the four possible second-step paths. After that, it is easy to find the likelihood that you reach $RB$, because it is the likelihood of first going to $R$ and then from $R$ going to $RB$.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to solve this problem yourself? It is a very elementary probability question that can be answered using the *rule of product*, which states that if there are $n$ ways of an event happening and $m$ ways of another event happening, there are $n \cdot m$ ways of both events happening.

The probability of the first marble being red is $\frac{9}{43}$. After returning this marble to the bag, the probability of the second marble being blue is $\frac{11}{43}$. So the probability picking a red marble, and then a blue marble is $\frac{9}{43} \cdot \frac{11}{43} \approx 0.054$.

Comment: As the marble is replaced(as per the question) shouldn't it be $\frac{9.11}{43.43}$ ?

Comment: @Ak19 You’re right. I didn’t read it properly!

Comment: Thank you for your time! This is not elementary whatsoever because my friends at another school haven't even heard about this yet. Thanks for your time again:)